# ListDensityPlot3D result in saved notebook doesn't show correctly

Tags: plotting, dynamic

Consider this example in the documentation of [`ListDensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot3D.html):

```
data = Table[
   Sin[x] Cos[y] Sin[z], {z, -5, 5, 0.1}, {y, -5, 5, 0.1}, {x, -5, 5, 
    0.1}];
ListDensityPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I tried this example in a notebook and it works as expected, but when I save and reopen the notebook, the image doesn't show correctly. I get a warning about dynamic content, and after click "Enable Dynamics" I get a gray image:

[image]

So why does the plot show correctly in the documentation but not in my notebook? Are there ways to fix that?

I'm using version 10.3.0.0 on OS X 10.11.

Comment: What version of mma and OS (including version) are you using?

Comment: @rcollyer I added the version information.

Comment: ok. I'll poke at it.

Comment: @rcollyer Sent. It seems that your mailbox has very small limit on the size of email message. I get rejected twice for ~10M attachment. Now it finally get through with ~6M attachment.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad I had you send that, I would never have guessed how our school mangled your name to get your address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are saving in one of the untrusted directories found under Preferences -> System. If you save to any directory not there, it works just fine. Of course, it should not remain gray after you have enabled dynamics.